# Windows, Block a process from Printing

Tags: windows, printing

Is their any way for a windows process to block another process from printing?

Basically we are trying to cut costs in the office and we want to block people from printing their emails. So I was asked if it was possible to write a program to block or cancel any print jobs comming from Outlook.

Can use a solution in any language or API, whatever works.

We have Win XP and Win 7 users.

Comment: I doubt this would help much. If you do succeed in blocking print jobs from Outlook, people will just save their email to another file and print that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There really isn't a good way to do this on Windows.

Besides, this doesn't seem like a technology problem.

Supply the printer with only one ream of paper per month.  Let everyone know that the paper supply is limited.

The obvious work around is that users will bring in their own paper, but that will greatly reduce the operating cost, so it's not really a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a network printer? If it is so, you can simply audit the printer's log (or the print server's) and "educate" your users accordingly, it will save you the hassle of writing such a program and deploy it on every pc (and make sure no user can override it).

Comment: Thats true, but we've tried educating people about saving paper. Simply put, some people just don't care. Also reviewing audit logs sounds like a lot of extra work for IT to be doing.
Beside, now that the question is asked, I would like to see the answer. Call it acedemic curiosity.

Comment: Then if you are using a printer server you could try to find out if your printer's driver have some kind of ACL. If there's no such thing, your're stuck with realizing the hack.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, this is the closest I could find for doing this. If basically waits for a print Job to show up with a particular job name and then cancel that job.

Technically though, I think the answer to my questing is no, since i asked if I could do this by process. Although the below comes close. It just prints out jobs that are happening and cancels any print job that says MS Outlook in its title. The dictionary thing just keeps it from listing the same jobs a bunch of times.

```
Imports System.Printing    
Module Module1
Sub Main()

    Using ps As New PrintServer("\\server")

        Using Pq = ps.GetPrintQueue("printer")

            Dim DetectedJobs As New Dictionary(Of DateTime, String)
            Do
                Dim Pj = Pq.GetPrintJobInfoCollection
                For Each job In Pj
                    If Not (DetectedJobs.ContainsKey(job.TimeJobSubmitted) AndAlso DetectedJobs(job.TimeJobSubmitted) = job.Name) Then
                        DetectedJobs.Add(job.TimeJobSubmitted, job.Name)
                        Console.WriteLine(job.Name & "," & job.JobIdentifier & "," & job.TimeJobSubmitted)
                    End If
                    If job.Name.Contains("Microsoft Office Outlook") Then
                        job.Cancel()
                        Console.WriteLine(job.Name & "," & job.JobIdentifier & "," & job.TimeJobSubmitted & " - Cancelled")
                    End If
                    job.Dispose()
                Next
                Pj.Dispose()

                Threading.Thread.Sleep("200")
            Loop

        End Using
    End Using

    Console.ReadKey()

End Sub

End Module
```